# Sibling fade class expanding beyond container

Tags: html, css, html-lists, pointer-events

Class of `.sibling-fade` is applying correctly on hover of the selected `<li>` element, however, it is being applied before the mouse enters the bordered area. Please see GIF below for an example.

**Example GIF**

[image: sibling-fade expanding beyong container]

**HTML**

```css
ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: table-row;
  height: 54px;
}

/* Sibling Fade */

.sibling-fade {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.sibling-fade > * {
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.sibling-fade > * {
  transition: opacity 150ms linear 100ms, ease-in-out 100ms;
}

.sibling-fade:hover > * {
  opacity: 0.4;
}

.sibling-fade > *:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay: 0ms, 0ms;
}
```

```html
<ul class="sibling-fade">
  <li><a href="one.html"><p class="title">Project One</p></a></li>
  <li><a href="two.html"><p class="title">Project Two</p></a></li>
  <li><a href="three.html"><p class="title">Project Three</p></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect `<li>` you will see that its width and height not exactly fit with its content, there are a couple of things causing this issue;

1. `<p class="title">` has top and bottom margin by default, remove it.
2. You have to remove `li {display: table-row;height: 54px;}`.

All of these are calculated with the element `width` and `height`.

So what I have done after doing the above steps:

1. add `li {display: inline-block;}`
2. add `<br>` after each `<li>`

```css
ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Sibling Fade */

.sibling-fade {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.sibling-fade > * {
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.sibling-fade > * {
  transition: opacity 150ms linear 100ms, ease-in-out 100ms;
}

.sibling-fade:hover > * {
  opacity: 0.4;
}

.sibling-fade > *:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay: 0ms, 0ms;
}
.title {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="sibling-fade">
  <li><a href="one.html"><p class="title">Project One</p></a></li><br>
  <li><a href="two.html"><p class="title">Project Two</p></a></li><br>
  <li><a href="three.html"><p class="title">Project Three</p></a></li><br>
</ul>
```

Comment: Glad to hear that!